# Rapidly emitting signals in Qt causes a segfault

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, qml

I am building an application using PyQt5 and QML (Qt 5.7.1) that controls a number of pieces of hardware and have run into a problem where emitting 10+ signals one after another causes the application to segfault. I attached a MWE to demonstrate the problem.

The MWE creates a background thread which then updates two labels in the main thread every millisecond using signals. The example segfaults in both Windows 7 and linux randomly, but generally in under a second. I installed the Qt debugging symbols in linux and found that it was segfaulting in random locations in QV4, though each call that segfaulted appeared to have something to do with the memory manager.

I've hit a dead end on what to do at this point, the only thing that stopped the segfaulting was to place `QThread.msleep()` calls between each signal emit, which has become untenable as the application grows.

This is my first time using Qt/QML so if this is not the correct way to use signals I apologize, but I can't find anything that says *don't* use them this way.

### StartPage.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    id: mainWindow

    ColumnLayout {
        Label {
            id: runLabel
            property int timesRun: 0

            text: "Number of times run: " + timesRun

            Connections {
                target: worker

                onDoSomethingDone: {
                    runLabel.timesRun = runLabel.timesRun + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        Label {
            id: dataLabel
            property real value: 0.0

            text: "Data: " + value

            Connections {
                target: worker

                onDataChanged: {
                    dataLabel.value = data
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### thread_test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import signal

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class Worker(QObject):

    doSomethingDone = pyqtSignal()
    dataChanged = pyqtSignal(float, arguments=['data'])
    runWorkSignal = pyqtSignal()

    _count = 0.0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.runWorkSignal.connect(self.do_something)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def do_something(self):
        while (True):
            self._count += 0.5

            self.doSomethingDone.emit()
            self.dataChanged.emit(self._count)

            QThread.msleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

    # Switch to the script directory so relative paths work correctly.
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    workObject = Worker()
    workThread = QThread()

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('worker', workObject)
    engine.load('qml/StartPage.qml')

    workThread.started.connect(workObject.do_something)
    workObject.moveToThread(workThread)
    workThread.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Try moving the worker object to the thread immediately after creation and before it is ever referenced by anything else. Sometimes things get confused if they're working with an object that hasn't yet been moved to the thread it is to run in.

Comment: @three_pineapples I had actually originally done it that way, but this threw an error in QML. Moving it to the thread after exporting it to QML made QML "happy," but was apparently also broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QML can not access another thread directly so if you connect an item to an object that is in another thread it causes problems like the one you observe. If you want to access another thread you must do it from the Python side, that is:

```
Worker(another thread) --> Proxy(main Thread) --> QML
```

In your case the solution is:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    [...]

class Proxy(QObject):
    doSomethingDone = pyqtSignal()
    dataChanged = pyqtSignal(float, arguments=['data'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

    # Switch to the script directory so relative paths work correctly.
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    workObject = Worker()
    workThread = QThread()
    proxy = Proxy()
    workObject.doSomethingDone.connect(proxy.doSomethingDone)
    workObject.dataChanged.connect(proxy.dataChanged)

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('worker', proxy)
    engine.load('qml/StartPage.qml')

    workThread.started.connect(workObject.do_something)
    workObject.moveToThread(workThread)
    workThread.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This fixed the problem, thank you so much! I had thought I was using Qt's signaling to pass data between threads correctly, I had no idea it would cause issues with QML.